# How to make mega menu centered at page width?

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js, megamenu

I'm learning tailwindCSS and AlpineJS and struggling to get the mega menu to take the full width of the gray nav-bar. It currently only takes the width of the content inside of it.

I've attached a link to the code pen below.

https://codepen.io/themegamenuguy/pen/jOQJJmx

Here is the raw code:

```html
<nav class="py-4" x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.window.escape="open = false">
  <div class="bg-gray-200 max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto px-4">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <a href="" class="mr-12">Brand</a>

        <div class="lg:flex hidden items-center">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-6">
            <div class="relative" x-data="{ open: false}">
              <button class="" type="button" @click="open = !open">
                <span class="font-medium">Mega Dropdown</span>
              </button>
              <div class="absolute border border-gray-50 bg-white mt-2 rounded-lg shadow-md" x-show="open" @click.away="open = false">
                test
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The menu only takes on the width of the text inside the mega menu.

I tried adjusting the width from auto to full and max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `absolute` positioned div is bound to the closest `relative` parent in the tree [(see CSS docs)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). In your code this is the `div` containing the button and the mega menu, but you want this to be the document `body`.

To fix this, first remove the `relative` from this div. Then you need to set the absolute placement of the mega menu div by using `left` and `right`, [see Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left).

Your code should now look like this:

```
<nav class="py-4" x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.window.escape="open = false">
  <div class="bg-gray-200 max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto px-4">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
      <div class="flex items-center">
        <a href="" class="mr-12">Brand</a>
        <div class="lg:flex hidden items-center">
          <div class="flex items-center space-x-6">
            <div class="" x-data="{ open: false}">
              <button class="" type="button" @click="open = !open">
                <span class="font-medium">Mega Dropdown</span>
              </button>
             <div class="absolute left-4 right-4 border border-gray-50 bg-white mt-2 rounded-lg shadow-md " x-show="open" @click.away="open = false">
                test
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```